# OneNote won't remember which lists are collapsed

Tags: microsoft-onenote, microsoft-onenote-2010

I use lists for many things in OneNote and they get big. But sometimes OneNote does not remember which parts of the lists I collapsed, so it shows them as expanded again next time I open OneNote.

Not EVERYTHING is expanded - only certain parts that I know I collapsed. And syncing does not change the outcome.

I've had this issue ever since I discovered that lists are collapsible (over a year ago). I assume it's a glitch, but is there a workaround to make sure OneNote remembers the collapse action?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This happens when you go to a page and all you do there is just collapsing a few lists.

List collapse is not executing automatic page save. In order to solve this, once you collapse all lists you want, you have to write and delete few letters into the page. Writing letters will execute page save, so after exit and return your list will be in the state you left them.